# no attribute 'reset_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing a LSTM NEURAL NETWORK on Tensorflow with google colab. But when I try to create a placeholder I find this error:

```
<ipython-input-62-1486afa70d57> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.reset_default_graph()
      2 
      3 X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES], name="input")
      4 Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_CLASSES])

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reset_default_graph
```

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
N_CLASSES = 6
N_HIDDEN_UNITS = 64
def create_LSTM_model(inputs):
    W = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS, N_CLASSES]))
    }
    biases = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS], mean=1.0)),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_CLASSES]))
    }
    
    X = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, N_FEATURES])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W['hidden']) + biases['hidden'])
    hidden = tf.split(hidden, N_TIME_STEPS, 0)

    # Stack 2 LSTM layers
    lstm_layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_UNITS, forget_bias=1.0) for _ in range(2)]
    lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)

    outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layers, hidden, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Get output for the last time step
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, W['output']) + biases['output']
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES], name="input")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_CLASSES])
```

What is wrong? Someone could please help me? Thank you so much

Comment: Try !pip show tensorflow. This will show you your tensorflow version. As far as I know, tf.placeholder() is deprecated and not available in the default tensorflow version colab has.

Comment: Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.3.0

Comment: Ok, it works with `tf.compat.v1.placeholder` and `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`

Comment: Ok, good. I added an answer on how to change tensorflow versions as well. I think your code is old and uses tf < 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.3.0 is the default version in Colab. I believe tf.reset_default_graph() and tf.placeholder() are only available in tf versions < 2.0 (when static graph definition was necessary). To switch tensorflow versions to 1.x in Colab, run

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

before you import tensorflow.
Reference here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb#scrollTo=-XbfkU7BeziQ